# Unity3D - Multiple dex file defines exception when building for android (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

We're trying to integrate Firebase Analytics into our project. Once we added the package, a bunch of play service resolvers ran and deleted a bunch of "obsolete" stuff. Following this, we were unable to Gradle build to Android, due to multiple dex files defining the same thing apparently. We tried deleting any duplicate .Jar, .aar and .Java files but to no avail. Honestly we have no idea how to fix this. It builds fine on a fresh project, so there has to be some conflict between our plugins but I have no idea what plugins it might be...

We would GREATLY appreciate anyone who can point us in the direction of solving this issue...

Cheers bretheren.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity201740f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$DisplayOptions;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 22s
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Foxie-Dev02\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Foxie-Dev02\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
The getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method instead.
The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Foxie-Dev02\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidArchLifecycleRuntime100Library
:prepareAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library
:prepareAppcompatV72531Library
:prepareCardviewV72531Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2610Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72610Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72610Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2610Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2610Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2610Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2610Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2610Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2610Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42610Library
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2610Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsIdentifier1600Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1601Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1601Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurementApi1602Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurementBase1603Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesStats1601Library
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1601Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1604Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1622Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsUnity540Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppUnity540Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1603Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1604Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1704Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIidInterop1601Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMeasurementConnector1701Library
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMeasurementConnectorImpl1702Library
:prepareCommonLibrary
:prepareCustomtabs2531Library
:prepareFacebookAndroidSdk4230Library
:prepareFacebookAndroidWrapper7100Library
:prepareGoogleAIDLLibrary
:prepareGooglePlayLibrary
:prepareShortcutBadger1121Library
:prepareSupportCompat2531Library
:prepareSupportCoreUi2531Library
:prepareSupportCoreUtils2531Library
:prepareSupportFragment2531Library
:prepareSupportMediaCompat2531Library
:prepareSupportV42531Library
:prepareSupportVectorDrawable2531Library
:prepareUtnotificationsLibrary
:Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
:Firebase:prepareReleaseDependencies
:Firebase:compileReleaseAidl
:Firebase:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:compileLint
:Firebase:copyReleaseLint NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
:Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
:Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
:Firebase:mergeReleaseAssets
:Firebase:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript
:Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
:Firebase:generateReleaseResources
:Firebase:packageReleaseResources
:Firebase:processReleaseManifest
:Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:Firebase:processReleaseResources
:Firebase:generateReleaseSources
:Firebase:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
:Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:Firebase:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:Firebase:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:Firebase:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:bundleRelease
:UTNotificationsRes:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:UTNotificationsRes:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:UTNotificationsRes:checkReleaseManifest
:UTNotificationsRes:prepareReleaseDependencies
:UTNotificationsRes:compileReleaseAidl
:UTNotificationsRes:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:UTNotificationsRes:compileLint
:UTNotificationsRes:copyReleaseLint NO-SOURCE
:UTNotificationsRes:mergeReleaseShaders
:UTNotificationsRes:compileReleaseShaders
:UTNotificationsRes:generateReleaseAssets
:UTNotificationsRes:mergeReleaseAssets
:UTNotificationsRes:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:UTNotificationsRes:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:UTNotificationsRes:compileReleaseRenderscript
:UTNotificationsRes:generateReleaseResValues
:UTNotificationsRes:generateReleaseResources
:UTNotificationsRes:packageReleaseResources
:UTNotificationsRes:processReleaseManifest
:UTNotificationsRes:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:UTNotificationsRes:processReleaseResources
:UTNotificationsRes:generateReleaseSources
:UTNotificationsRes:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:UTNotificationsRes:javaPreCompileRelease
:UTNotificationsRes:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:UTNotificationsRes:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:UTNotificationsRes:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:UTNotificationsRes:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:UTNotificationsRes:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:UTNotificationsRes:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:UTNotificationsRes:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:UTNotificationsRes:bundleRelease
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:processReleaseManifest
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:javaPreCompileRelease
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseSources
:lintVitalRelease
:mergeReleaseShaders
:compileReleaseShaders
:generateReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED
110 actionable tasks: 110 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

**build.gradle** (note: The following code changed over the course of fixing the bug. Certain dependencies were removed in order to fix our issue).

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.appcompat-v7-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.cardview-v7-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.customtabs-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-ui-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-core-utils-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-fragment-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-26.1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier-16.0.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-api-16.0.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-base-16.0.3', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-stats-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-16.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-unity-5.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-app-unity-5.4.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-common-16.0.3', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-core-16.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-17.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-interop-16.0.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-17.0.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.2', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'customtabs-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'facebook-android-wrapper-7.10.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'ShortcutBadger-1.1.21', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'utnotifications', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':Firebase')
    compile project(':UTNotificationsRes')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 28
        applicationId 'com.FoxieGames.WolfEvolution'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb','bin/data/02699eb9bf049e34598159ce0c81ab0f.resource','bin/data/08747c70106469044be87a8d49638bfd.resource','bin/data/087513eb2f44ea743aeacc30213c8e54.resource','bin/data/0f59709ea21789946b44eae3449dd2cf.resource','bin/data/12fef1f7c084d48409227f6f97183d68.resource','bin/data/1dfac539090e8e047804208581cb9b4a.resource','bin/data/2487cd62d993a6c408d6503c8a2ce659.resource','bin/data/2a1889f3a216a7846b140198c0dc6789.resource','bin/data/31c65f2a7d05ceb41bc749705cf0ac39.resource','bin/data/3f8667afc6eb3a34abd32d67a9be862d.resource','bin/data/461ab6af92be8be41bbb40c574863ab5.resource','bin/data/520314cd8ed60db4e8bc546698fbf49d.resource','bin/data/553b4b5b8a29d6143819a791e91bc9f4.resource','bin/data/55bc945adf097cc45a5675ca38f98637.resource','bin/data/69c1986c4f406f049914a0f0a67b11e7.resource','bin/data/6aebc8a7d3f190440b755fb3304d1b0e.resource','bin/data/6fd2fed6e57460d458f58b109f47be5f.resource','bin/data/8d08e130764187b41a241b8e63b450b3.resource','bin/data/922b6541a64ee4b40ab51555138f20a5.resource','bin/data/9e9e4236384f1cd42820f71e2c7e924d.resource','bin/data/a431a3cd6f471bc4eb32c1d1272c35b4.resource','bin/data/b6651b55bfa61d24fa857ddc20e4f1d7.resource','bin/data/b6d1c852ce9b65a4d955ce5505b3f6c0.resource','bin/data/b735612a2c95ec0469e1d40ef7b0b6f9.resource','bin/data/c864fb8ea19443a4a9738a389bd28a0a.resource','bin/data/c8ddb94b8baefbe4284af958325d02a5.resource','bin/data/caad8e9ba87307142b93f9fe6e0a2ef7.resource','bin/data/d78fe5dc8845f8d4d9e12f38c8c7fc75.resource','bin/data/e09fb570c3608074ba5c637de3b51f67.resource','bin/data/e7a18ee69637edb42b7938def055bd20.resource','bin/data/f27a19dea138ebc4ca4f19a6983fce87.resource','bin/data/f6a0424e3fb957e48887b89f2a9c97c0.resource','bin/data/f8fc0e1ee67ff07499cdbbbd47d18d98.resource','bin/data/sharedassets0.resource','bin/data/sharedassets1.resource'
    }

    signingConfigs { release {
        storeFile file('C:/myprojects/keystores/keystore_wolfevolution.keystore')
        storePassword 'teamfoxie'
        keyAlias 'foxie games'
        keyPassword 'teamfoxie'
    } }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you use Gradle system ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya yes!

Comment: Post full Gradle.

Comment: Try to export the unity project as Android Studio project, so that you can enable mulidex in gradle build.

Comment: @HarishJose I tried enabling this before, but when I tried to build, the console said that multidex is not supported :<

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya 1 moment please!

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I added the build.gradle sir, down the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Issue is two `appcompat` library with different version.
Check

Many Library have duplicate.

Remove them and update all version from `25.3.1` to `26.1.0`.

Comment: hmmm I deleted the 25.3.1 lib... Still receiving the same error.

I don't suppose you can see other duplicate libraries? I can't see myself... Edit: Wait I can see... I'll get back to you when I delete them

Comment: Okay so I removed a few more dupe libraries... However I am still getting the same issue. I've updated the build.gradle... can you see anything else I've forgotten? Perhaps this line? ------------------------------------

compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-17.0.1', ext:'aar') --------------------------

compile(name: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-impl-17.0.2', ext:'aar')

Comment: `compile(name: 'customtabs-25.3.1', ext:'aar')`

Comment: Yes! I just found it haha.

Thank you so much sir! I spent so much time trying to fix this today I almost thought we would have to leave out this feature.

Have a good day and thank you again!